# Can you use the fields from one Dynamics CRM 365 entity in another?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have an address entity that has fields address1, address2, city, state, zipcode.  I want to use the fields from the address entity for forms in other entities.  I have searched online for a solution, but can only find solutions about copying data from one entity to another.  I would think with SQL Server as the engine, that I could create some type foreign key relationship.

Our CRM instance is hosted in the cloud, not on-premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/259036) to learn about OOB Address entity limitations.

If you have custom address entity, then you can create a lookup of that custom address entity in any Entity (let’s say EntityA), this will add a Foreign key of address in EntityA.

You can use Quick view form of Address Entity in EntityA form to display the fields of Address record chosen in lookup.

Anyway you cannot use any other entity (A) fields for data entry in another entity (B) form. Maybe you have to recreate placeholder fields to collect data & sync over between entities.

Comment: So are you saying that I can't embed address entity fields in my person form from my person entity?  I would have to recreate the same fields in every entity?

Comment: @user1647160 yes, OOB Entity Form don’t have that option (you might have noticed it in form editor). only view editor will allow it to add fields in grid from associated entity records.